# Same data with different instances have different legend objects on plotly.express

Tags: plotly

Can we have the same data information, same name and legend for different subplots on plotly figure? Currently, I got different plot colors, which is somewhat confusing. Below, there is a code sample

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Sample data
data = {
    'year': [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004],
    'A': [1, 3, 2, 5, 4],
    'B': [2, 4, 1, 6, 3],
    'C': [3, 2, 4, 3, 2],
    'D': [4, 3, 5, 2, 1]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

colors = {'A': 'blue', 'B': 'orange', 'C': 'green', 'D': 'red'}

# Create subplots
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, subplot_titles=['Stacked Area A-B', 'Stacked Area C-D'])

# Add stacked area plots to subplots
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df['year'], y=df['A'], fill='tozeroy', name='A', stackgroup='one', line_color=colors['A']
), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df['year'], y=df['A'], fill='tonexty', name='B', stackgroup='one', line_color=colors['B']
), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df['year'], y=df['A'], fill='tonexty', name='C', stackgroup='one', line_color=colors['C']
), row=1, col=2)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=df['year'], y=df['A'], fill='tonexty', name='A', stackgroup='one', line_color=colors['A']
), row=1, col=2)

# Update x-axis and y-axis labels
fig.update_xaxes(title_text='Year', row=1, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text='Value', row=1, col=1)

fig.update_xaxes(title_text='Year', row=1, col=2)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text='Value', row=1, col=2)

# Update layout
fig.update_layout(showlegend=True, hovermode='x', title='Stacked Area Subplots')
```

The code above outputs the image below:

[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC8Ji.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about your goal? A manually edited version of your current output is fine.

Comment: I editted OP for better comprehension